# I can't get parameter names from valuetuple via reflection in c# 7.0

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I want to Map a ValueTuple to a class using reflection.
Documentation says that there is a Attribute attached to ValueTuple with parameters names (others than Item1, Item2, etc...) but I can't see any Attribute.

Disassembly shows nothing.

What's happens?

Example:

```
public static T ToStruct<T, T1,T2>(this ValueTuple<T1,T2> tuple) where T : struct
```

Via reflection can't get Item1, Item2 names to match with T fields via reflection.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should have the `TupleElementNames` attribute on the method created by the compiler.

See [this code](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgApIyGDQA0MQTCIBKGAFk+Mtrk4qY7VRwBOqZME0R+ARjEAmKTmWcAvnitA===):

```
public class C {
    public (int a, int b) M() {

        return (1, 2);
    }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
[return: TupleElementNames(new string[] {
    "a",
    "b"
})]
public ValueTuple<int, int> M()
{
    return new ValueTuple<int, int>(1, 2);
}
```

You can get that attribute using this code:

```
Type t = typeof(C);
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(nameof(C.M));
var attr = method.ReturnParameter.GetCustomAttribute<TupleElementNamesAttribute>();

string[] names = attr.TransformNames;
```

Comment: public static T ToStruct<T, T1>(this ValueTuple<T1,T2> tuple) where T : struct
Compiler NO adds anything to Match ValueTuple<T1,T2> with TupleElementNames...

Comment: It is valid only to RETURN a ValueTuple. I want use a ValueTuple as Input, not output

Comment: No, it is valid for method arguments too. In your code you won't have any arguments since you use the `ValueType` itself. If you would use the actual type it could have.

Comment: There is no other possibility. I have to admit ANY valuetuple to map to

Comment: We can talk for very long about this, but it won't work, as already said. The `ValueType` itself doesn't hold that kind of information, so when you use that type, you are lost.

Answer (score 12):

As Patrick pointed out above, you can use reflection to inspect the tuple names used in the declaration of your method. 
But that gives you no information given that your `ToStruct` method signature shows no names.
And, in any case, that gives you no information about tuples that will actually be passed into that method.

The runtime type is only `ValueTuple` (no names). The names only help at compile time, as syntactic sugar for `ItemN`.

---

From the [design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/tuples.md):

### Name erasure at runtime

Importantly, the tuple field names aren't part of the runtime representation of tuples, but are tracked only by the compiler.

As a result, the field names will not be available to a 3rd party observer of a tuple instance - such as **reflection or dynamic code**.

---

You can read more about that at http://mustoverride.com/tuples_names/