# Converting Dictionary with tuple and enum to JSON

Tags: c#, enums, json.net, tuples

In my class, I have an enum definition as followed:

```
public enum ChangeType { 
  [EnumMember(Value ="Added")]
  Added,
  [EnumMember(Value = "Removed")]
  Removed,
  [EnumMember(Value = "Updated")]
  Updated 
}
```

And in the class definition, I have a property:

```
public 
  Dictionary<string, (ChangeType changType, string oldValue, string newValue)> 
  PropertyChanges { get; set; }
```

Requirements:

1. When converting to JSON, changeType should be in text, not number
2. Tuple should be converted w/ the name of the items instead of Item1, Item2 and Item3

What I have tried:

- As for the enum, I tried putting the JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] in front of the property (no go)
- Cannot any recommendation about the named tuples

Question:

**Can I achieve the above without writing a custom converter to convert the whole class?**

Thanks!

Comment: How do you serialize instance of your dictionary?

Comment: Also "Tuple should be converted w/ the name of the items instead of Item1, Item2 and Item3" can't be achieved cause your tuple is actually `ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3>` and does not actually have `changType`, `oldValue`, `newValue` members. You will need to create class/struct for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not as bad as I thought...
JsonConvert.SerializeObject() already has already done a pretty good job serializing the Dictionary<>, so all I have to do is to help Json to interpret the enum and the tuple.

First, I create a class called **CustomTupleConverter** that implements **JsonConverter<(ChangeType changeType, string oldValue, string newValue)>**.

In the implementation of WriteJson(), I have the following:

```
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("Action");
writer.WriteValue(value.changeType.ToString());
writer.WritePropertyName("OldValue");
writer.WriteValue(value.oldValue.ToString());
writer.WritePropertyName("NewValue");
writer.WriteValue(value.newValue.ToString());
writer.WriteEndObject();
```

When invoking the **JsonConvert.SerializeObject()**, I simply add the instantiation of my converter to the call:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cc, Formatting.Indented, new CustomTupleConverter());
```

That's it.

Comment: But now this will be invoked for _any_ `(ChangeType, string, string)` tuple, regardless of its member names within `cc`. It will also print "Action" as property name, even if you later decide to rename it. Or how do you implement `CanWrite`? This may not be what you want. Also, creating a `public class Change { public ChangeType Action { get; set;} public string OldValue { get;set; } public string NewValue { get; set; } }` is way less code and more portable than this solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster...this for the recommendation...we are so deep in the rabbit hole w/ the tuple at this moment, converting it w/ a struct and class doesn't seem feasible.  To answer your question about CanWrite(): since I am using JsonConverter<>, overriding CanWrite() is not required since it will only work with the specific value tuple.  I have to agree with you that making the tuple a struct or a class will definitely make my life easier.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The names of ValueTuple keys basically don't exist after compilation, [except for in some attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488888/i-cant-get-parameter-names-from-valuetuple-via-reflection-in-c-sharp-7-0), so the type info that the serializer gets doesn't contain the names.

So you'll have to use a class to control the serialized names, instead of that ValueTuple.