# How to make XmlSerialize/XmlDeserialize use ValueTuple names?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, valuetuple

Using `XmlSerialize` I serialized a class with a ValueType:

```
public (int x, int y) coord;
```

And got this result:

```xml
<coord>
  <Item1>1<Item1/>
  <Item2>2<Item2/>
<coord/>
```

I expected the serializer to use the name I provided but clearly it didn't. Modifying the xml to x and y results in a silent failure, setting (0,0) instead of (1,2).

Is there a way to get `ValueTuple` names to work `XmlSerialize`/`XmlDeserialize`?

Comment: Not that I know of.  XmlSerializer uses reflection to get the property names, and the actual property names in `ValueTuple<T1, T2>` are `Item1` and `Item2`.  See the [design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/tuples.md#name-erasure-at-runtime): ***Name erasure at runtime:**  Importantly, the tuple field names aren't part of the runtime representation of tuples, but are tracked only by the compiler. As a result, the field names will not be available to a 3rd party observer of a tuple instance - such as reflection or dynamic code.*

Comment: See also [I can't get parameter names from valuetuple via reflection in c# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43488888).  There is an attribute [`TupleElementNamesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.tupleelementnamesattribute?view=net-7.0) which is applied in various places (such as method returns) to "hint" the current tuple item names, but clearly XmlSerializer does not use it.

Comment: My recommendation would be to make some DTO with the correct names, and serialize that.