# C# How to get Tuple property names

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, tuples

I am struggling with getting tuple property names.

The following example:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World: {0}", string.Join(", ", GetProps<(int Site, int Location)>()));
}
    
public static string[] GetProps<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).GetFields().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Gives me the result: `Hello World: Item1, Item2`

Does anyone know how to get `Hello World: Site, Location` instead?

Playground: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dzfM2x

Comment: The property names of a `ValueTuple` are indeed `Item1`, `Item2` and so on.  See e.g. [Make Value Tuple property names resolvable at runtime #1906](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/1906).  You can try to get the value of the `TupleElementNamesAttribute` attribute on a parameter or return method via reflection, see e.g. [I can't get parameter names from valuetuple via reflection in c# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43488888).

Comment: Still cannot get it working https://dotnetfiddle.net/81UlYv :-(

Comment: You can't get it working because the tuple names are not a property of the tuple types.   This limitation is explicitly documented by MSFT in [Tuple field names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names): *At compile time, the compiler replaces non-default field names with the corresponding default names. **As a result, explicitly specified or inferred field names aren't available at run time.***  The only thing you can get at runtime are the tuple field names used by a particular tuple member, return value or parameter.